# Communication between VB6 and VB.Net applications

Tags: vb.net, vb6, named-pipes

Hi I have two applications one wrote in VB6 and the other in VB.Net and I'm trying to find a way how they can talk each other. I don't need anything complex, just sending 12 char long string would be enough. I found nice article which uses Windows messages for this purpose but it doesn't send strings just integers. I also seen quite a lot information about named pipes but on VB.Net, and not much on VB6.

What is the best way to connect those two applications?

Comment: Are these on the same machine or different machines?

Comment: they are located on the same machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way would be to use WCF.

Getting Started: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33995/Getting-Started-with-WCF

You can do this natively in the .NET application and for the VB6 application; create a .NET assembly to do the WCF part and communicate to this via COM Interop

Answer (score 0):

Late answer: try a common folder and simply create a file in it and read ist contents. in .NET with a file watcher. Should be the most easy way to communicate across auch old and new worlds.